# What does the regex /=$/ do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Found it in the rails source in the method missing call:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/57cfa7a98fee14c7b61f5d4930ca05ae262e9a91/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb

What does it do?

Comment: put the code of confusion here also..

Comment: It checks to see if the string ends with an equals sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is just a literal "="

`$` is an regex meta character, an [**anchor**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Anchors) that matches the end of the line

So the regex `/=$/` is true, when the last char in a line is a "=".

You can test your ruby regexes at rubular.com. [**See yours!**](http://www.rubular.com/r/yOSFjJKjhh)

Comment: Actually it matches the `=` that is at the end of a line. Which is truthy, but not exactly true.

Answer (score 1):

It will check if the string ends with an equals sign or not.